# How to bundle CSS file based on angular environment

Tags: angular

I want to know if there is any way to bundle external CSS files to my app based on the angular environment.

For example I have `style-dev.scss` and `style-prod.scss`. If the app is running in development mode, the compiler should bundle the `style-dev.scss` file and otherwise `style-prod.scss`.

Angular version 5.0.5

Comment: What do you mean with the "CLI environment"? The switch between prod and non-prod is done within Angular itself and is not directly related to the Angular-CLI.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that @OddDev. I've updated my question

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with the different style-file-solution? I have the strong feeling that this is a case of the so called [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I don't think this is an XY Problem @OddDev. I think the example I gave is straightforward, if not then I might be asking `how does the angular compiler work` which I suppose to be a much broader subject IMHO.

Comment: the XY Problem is not about your example. XY Problem in this case means that you are trying to solve a specific problem with the solution of two separate style-files. You need to explain this problem. Or the other way around: why do you need two separate style-files for the environments?